# Drop DB2 table if exists

Tags: perl, db2

In my script I have to do a lot of selects to a joined table, so instead I decided to put this join into a temporal table.

First I thought:

```
1. Create table
2. Put the data from the join into a table
3. Drop the table
```

But then I thought, what if the script fails before I dropped the table?

So I decided to go with:

```
1. Drop the table
2. Create the table
3. Put the data from the join into a table
```

I don't really mind if the table is left there until the next time I run the script, so the second option works too.

But what if somebody had already dropped the table?

I saw some systems have a "drop if exists" but unfortunately not DB2. I would like to do something that won't make the script die when the drop table fails.

Ideas? On any of this? Thanks!

EDIT: I forgot to say this is in a PERL script!

Comment: You can check for the existence of a given table using [`$dbh->tables`](http://search.cpan.org/~hoymich/DBD-DB2-0.78-5.8.4/lib/DBD/DB2.pod#Getting_Table_information)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is by using an annonymous block like in this [code](https://github.com/angoca/log4db2/blob/master/src/test/sql-pl/Tests_LOG4DB2_APPENDERS.sql#L38)

You need to call the drop table in a dynamic sql, and catch the exception in the block.

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
begin
  declare statement varchar(128);
  declare continue handle for sqlstate '42710' BEGIN END;
  SET STATEMENT = 'DROP TABLE MYTABLE';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE STATEMENT;
end @
```

This code will run normally in DB2. It does not need to be part of a procedure nor function.

Comment: we should learn to copy paste without syntax errors      (HANDLER)

Answer (score 0):

Why not look for the table first? If you find it, it needs to be dropped; if you don't, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

db2perf_quiet_drop that might works the way you want..  Its a free add-on :)

You can look into this post too..

http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1609047-DB2-equivalent-for-mysql-s-DROP-TABLE-IF-EXISTS

If this doesn't work for you please let me know what error you are getting so I can try to help :)

Or this might work
 if( NOT exists( create table detailval
(
   id int,
   detaildeptNo int,
   info varchar(255)
);
insert into detailval(1,1, 'detail values A');
insert into detailval(2,1, 'detail values B');
insert into detailval(3,1, 'detail values C');
insert into detailval(4,2, 'detail values D');

```
        )  
)   
then customStoredproc('droptable');
```

end if;

End

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into working with temporary tables (**DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE**). They are stored in the temporary table space and are dropped automatically after commit.

You can easily also query syscat.tables like this:

`select COUNT(*) from SYSCAT.TABLES where TRIM(TABNAME) = '<some_table_name>'`

if this query returns 0 then the table does not exists.